# How to get recommendations for new user in coreML MLRecommender model?

Tags: coreml, coremltools

I have a dataset with 3 columns "item_id", "user_id", "rating".  I created a `coreML` `MLRecommender` model from this dataset.

I want to use this model to get the top 10 predictions for a new user (not in the original dataset) but who has rated a subset of the items in the dataset.

I don't see any API in the Apple docs to do this.  Both the `recommendations` APIs only accept an existing user-id and get recommendations for that user.  This seems like a strange API design and hopefully I am missing something.

The WWDC tutorial talks about a `prediction` API to achieve this.  But I dont see this in the Apple API documentation and code below from WWDC tutorial will not work since it does not give details on how to create the `HikingRouteRecommenderInput` class it passes into the prediction API)

`let hikes : [String : Double] = ["Granite Peak" : 5, "Wildflower Meadows" : 4] let input = HikingRouteRecommenderInput(items: hikes, k: 5) // Get results as sequence of recommended items let results = try model.prediction(input: input)`

Any pointers on how to get predictions for new user would be greatly appreciated

I don't see a prediction API listed in Apple documentation.  Hence, I am not sure on how to proceed.